# Android - Pause the for-loop till the AsyncTask Completed Successfully

Tags: android, for-loop, asynchronous, android-asynctask

The results object holds N number of JSON array value.
The for-loop runs (initiate) the second array value before the first async task completed.I want to execute and move to the next array value,only after the current one gets finished successfully,If NOT wait for it to complete

```
if (results.length() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = results
                .getJSONObject(i);
        FeedDataType item = new FeedDataType(
                object);
        AsyncTasks performBackgroundTask = new AsyncTasks();
        performBackgroundTask.execute(item);
        DBadapter.add(item);
        Log.e("Aynsc Task",performBackgroundTask.getStatus().toString());
    }
}
```

Log results shows only **Pending** (or) **Running** but Not **Finished**.
Give me a solution that doesn't affect the UI.
And,I don't want to use get() method on Asynctask class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asynck task try to override opPostExecute method.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

         return null;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         //This will call after doInBackground finished.
     }
 }
```

**Write your code under onPostExecte method**

Comment: No,that's not helpful...I dont want that..I just need to know whether the async task get completed...

Comment: If possible,What I needed is,<br/>
Should run code every N seconds,and Can able to stop and re-start when completed the previous

Comment: Once it enter to the onPostexecute method Async task wll completed.. What else do you want?

Comment: Please read the description carefully.The for-loop goes on to the next iteration before the previous one completed....I want to wait the for-loop till the async task complete and save the images

Comment: I done that once. If you do that your UI will freeze . If you want tell me I will tell you what I done. I am sure that is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

The Async Task is been used as below

```
 private class TaskBK extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     //This will call after the doInBackground method get completed.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       // This will get executed before doInBackground method get executed
    }
}
```

Comment: No use...I don't want to do that in Asynctask class

Comment: You can create an background service and do this process,   

IF you still need to use the Async Task you can have an listener (interface) which get trigger on the onPostExcecute

Answer (score -1):

Was facing the same problem. The thing is you cannot 'pause' the loop, instead what you can do give the loop a delay to give time for the async task to finish running.
Try arounf 3 seconds of delay. This is how to do it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = results
                .getJSONObject(i);
        FeedDataType item = new FeedDataType(
                object);
        AsyncTasks performBackgroundTask = new AsyncTasks();
        performBackgroundTask.execute(item);
        DBadapter.add(item);
        Log.e("Aynsc Task",performBackgroundTask.getStatus().toString());
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
```

The main Thread will sleep delay for three seconds allowing async task to finish execution an the loop will proceed after the delay. Give an upvote if you find this helpful.